# Mounting a sparsebundle in OS X (specifically Time Machine)

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, time-machine, sparsebundle

I have a (not critical) problem, that seems to have been introduced with 10.6.4.

I backup using Time Machine to an Airport disk (same as a Time Capsule). But if I mount the sparsebundle image manually in Finder (for example, to use Backup Loupe), the performance has now become almost unusable. Clicking on a folder in Finder can take a minute to display the contents.

But if I use a program (such as TimeTracker) which mounts the image automatically, or if I try and browse the image while Time Machine has mounted it and is backing up, I get normal performance. So, I know it is not network.

It just seems if I mount it in Finder (and of course, I have to mount the drive as well first), then I get the slow performance. I can't be 100% that it is 10.6.4 related, but I can't think why it suddenly is like this. But when it is mounted by TimeTracker or Time Machine itself, they have a hidden way to mount the drive.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the mounted image to the Spotlight privacy panel, and see if that helps.

It sounds like Time Machine & Time Tracker, are mounting it in a manner that Spotlight is not indexing it.  Whereas if you do it manually, it is being indexed...

That could explain the performance difference..